# Does anyone know where I can get the continued fraction representation of the Lambert W function?

Tags: continued-fractions, lambert-w

[Wikipedia's image for the representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL1Fi.png)

I was just wondering if anyone has an extended version of it. (Like a longer fraction so it is more accurate)

I need to get further than the 94423 term in

x/(1+x/(1+x/(2+3x/(3+17x/(10+1927x/(190+13582711x/(94423 ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The Mathematica code here does what you want.

```
ClearAll[cf, x];
cf[ O[x]] = {};
cf[ a0_ + O[x]] := {a0};
cf[ ps_] := Module[ {a0, a1, u, v}, 
  a0 = SeriesCoefficient[ ps, {x, 0, 0}];
  a1 = SeriesCoefficient[ ps, {x, 0, 1}];
  u = Numerator[a1]; v = Denominator[a1];
  Join[ If[ a0==0, {}, {a0}],
     Prepend[cf[ u*x/(ps-a0) - v], {u,v}]]];

(* Lambert W function W_0(x) up to O(x)^(M+1) *)
M = 10; W0 = Sum[ x^n*(-n)^(n-1)/n!, {n, 1, M}] + x*O[x]^M;
cf[W0] //InputForm
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 3}, {17, 10}, {133, 17}, 
 {1927, 190}, {13582711, 94423}, {92612482895, 1597966}, 
 {10402118970990527, 8773814169}} *)
```

Where the `M = 10` can be set to how many terms you want.

Comment: I don't have mathematica, is there a clearer formula that i can perhaps use in desmos?

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Mathematica in the Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com) with a free account.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Asking for the "derivation" is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple, it's $$\frac{a_1 x}{b_1 + \frac{a_2 x}{b_2 + \ldots}}$$ where
$[a_i, b_i]$ are
$$ [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [5, 3], [17, 10], [133, 17], [1927, 190], [13582711, 94423], [92612482895 , 1597966], [10402118970990527 , 8773814169], [59203666396198716260449 ,10796179523602],\ldots$$

The $a_i$ and $b_i$ seem not to be in the OEIS.

Comment: As a quick question do you know how to find the [exact continued fraction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ProductLog+continued+fraction+identity+1&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22ContinuedFraction%22%2C+%7B%22ProductLog%22%2C+1%7D%7D) of the function?